# Select and update multiple rows from a database table with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a database table named coins

```
id | owner_id | amount
1  |    3     |  1000 
2  |    22    |  250 
3  |    45    |  450 
4  |    21    |  300
......
```

The question is:
There are 2000 coins that are owned by others.

If a user buys 600 coins, 600 coins must be taken away from other users.
What is the best way to select (only rows with a total amount of 600 coins total) and update the table coins?

Because no one has exactly 600 coins. The coins must be taken away from someone who owns at least 600 coins or from several people who have a combined minimum of 600

Comment: Could you give an example of how the data should look like after the update is performed? It would help make the question clearer.

Comment: I guess it depends on what your logic is for taking the 600 coins away from other users. to select a row with exactly 600, you'd use something like `SELECT * FROM coins WHERE amount = 600`

Comment: `What is the best` needs a measure of quality. You don't even mention indexes.

Comment: _"Because no one has exactly 600 coins"_ - And we know that how?

Answer (score 0):

```
$MoreThan600 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `owner_id` FROM `table` WHERE `amount` > 599 ORDER BY `amount` DESC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($MoreThan600) > 0){
    $ownerQ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `owner_id` FROM `table` WHERE `amount` > 599 ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $owner_id = mysqli_fetch_array($ownerQ);
    // access owner id with $owner_id[0] and do the coin exchange here
}else{
    // do others have in total ahve more than 600?
    $x = 0;
    $participants = array();
    $people = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
    while($person_info = mysqli_fetch_array($people)){
        $x+=$person_info['amount'];
        if($x > 599){
            break; // no more people needed.
        }else{
            array_push($participants, $person_info['owner_id']);
        }
    }

    // now take all their money(fairly)!
    $tax = 600 / count($people);
    $leftovers = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($people); $i++){
        $walletQ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `amount` FROM `table` WHERE `owner_id`='$people[$i]'");
        $old_amount = mysqli_fetch_array($walletQ);
        if($old_amount < round($tax)){
            // take all their money
            $leftovers += (round($tax) - $old_amount);
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `table` SET `amount`='0' WHERE `owner_id`='$people[$i]'");
        }else{
            $new_amount = $old_amount[0] - round($tax);
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `table` SET `amount`='$new_amount' WHERE `owner_id`='$people[$i]'");
        }
    }

    if($leftovers > 0){
        // Someone (or people) will pay for leftovers
        $debtQ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `owner_id` FROM `table` WHERE `amount` > '$leftovers'");
        if(mysqli_num_fields($debtQ) > 0){
            $owner_id = mysqli_fetch_array($debtQ);
            // access owner id with $owner_id[0] and make him pay for debt
        }else{
            // take everyones money until its paid (unfairly)
            while($person = mysqli_fetch_array($people)){
                $money = $person['amount'];
                mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `table` SET `amount`='0' WHERE `owner_id`='$person[$i]'");
                $leftovers -= $money;
                if($leftovers < 1){
                    // success. debt paid
                    echo "success";
                    // give 600 to the kiddo
                    break;
                }
            }

            // check if the while loop worked to pay debt
            if($leftovers > 0){
                // i guess everyone is poor. thus as a collective they all cant pay 600
                echo "No one can pay 600, everyone cant pay 600 even when combined";
            }
        }
    }else{
        // give 600 to the kiddo
    }


    # END! :D
}
```

"several people who have a combined minimum of 600" <- their ids are stored in an array called $participants

Where ive commented give 600 to the kiddo, you should make a query to give 600 coins to the winner. and where i put do coin exchange, you need to take away 600 from `$id = $owner_id[0]` and give it to the winner

any questinons? have i gone wrong somewhere? how can i improve my code?

Comment: completed i guess?